# EJS - How to link anchor tag to the external websites?

Tags: node.js, ejs, viewengine

I am trying to navigate to external sites in ejs templating engine. However it is taking link in the anchor tag as one of the  routes of my application so it is opening link as follows: `http://localhost:3000/www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtLJEhexrxY`

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Search results for <%=term %></h1>
    <% videos.forEach((video)=>{ %>
        <a href="www.youtube.com">Search</a>
        <a target=_blank href="www.youtube.com/watch?v=<%=video["id"]["videoId"]%>">
        <img src="<%=video["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["medium"]["url"]%>" alt="">
        </a>
            <div>

                <h3><%=video["snippet"]["title"]%></h3>
                <h4><%=video["snippet"]["publishedAt"]%></h4>
                <p><%=video["snippet"]["description"]%></p>
            </div>
        <br>
    <% }) %>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to navigate to youtube.com but it is navigating to localhost:300/www.youtube.com

Comment: Make sure you add http:// to the front of external links! Otherwise it's an internal link!

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. I added http:// prefix at the beginning. Thanks to [ngearing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3377620/ngearing)